# How to Secure a port opened in the host?

Tags: perl

Our goal is to monitor the server up/down from a remote(central) server. For this we are opening a port in the target host using the below (Client_port.pl) script. On the server we have other script to monitor this port, to make sure the server is up and port is up. Both the server wouldn't be on same network, so we need to open the client port to the world. How would we secure the client port from security hole and other possible harmful issues?

Client_port.pl

```
use IO::Socket::INET;

$server = IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalPort => $server_port,
                                Type      => SOCK_STREAM,
                                Reuse     => 1,
                                Listen    => 10 )   # or SOMAXCONN
    or die "Couldn't be a tcp server on port $server_port: $!\n";

while ($client = $server->accept()) {
    # $client is the new connection
}

close($server);
```

Server_port_listener.pl

```
use strict;
use Socket;

# set time until connection attempt times out
my $timeout = 3;

if ($#ARGV != 1) {
  print "usage: is_tcp_port_listening hostname portnumber\n";
  exit 2;
}

my $hostname = $ARGV[0];
my $portnumber = $ARGV[1];
my $host = shift || $hostname;
my $port = shift || $portnumber;
my $proto = getprotobyname('tcp');
my $iaddr = inet_aton($host);
my $paddr = sockaddr_in($port, $iaddr);

socket(SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto) || die "socket: $!";

eval {
  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "timeout" };
  alarm($timeout);
  connect(SOCKET, $paddr) || error();
  alarm(0);
};

if ($@) {
  close SOCKET || die "close: $!";
  print "$hostname is NOT listening on tcp port $portnumber.\n";
  exit 1;
}
else {
  close SOCKET || die "close: $!";
  print "$hostname is listening on tcp port $portnumber.\n";
  exit 0;
}
```

Comment: You would secure it by throwing this code out and using a real monitoring system.

Comment: use ssh script to monitor or what @jordanm said

Comment: Assuming you don't follow jordanm's worthy suggestion, you could  poke a port that's already open on the server; since it's a server, presumably it's already listening on at least one TCP port, so you can just try that port and see if you get a connection. Bonus: this also tells you whether or not the specific service of interest is up, rather than just whether the server is responding to TCP connection requests at all. (And you also don't have to worry about securing another port, or handling cases where your server-side responder has fallen over but the services of actual interest have not.)

Comment: I need to this way because there are many servers to monitor.@aaron we can t depend on any service, firstly the ports open ll not be same and if the service port is under maintenance we don't want sending wrong alert.

Comment: To add to what @jordanm said, there are already [many](http://www.nagios.org/) [existing](http://www.opennms.org/) [solutions](http://community.zenoss.org/index.jspa) to monitor network health. These solutions are significantly more robust and scalable than anything you will hack together yourself. Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I probably don't need lot of services provided by the existing solutions, so I would like to write our own method for this so it would be very light weight.